# Any excellent rdf graph visualisation tools that comes with a SPARQL query editor or browser?

Tags: graph, rdf, sparql

As per my question, I'm curious is anybody out there in the community knows any useful tools that could accomplish this ie you have sparql query editor which allows you to write and save your queries and retrieves your results in a visual graph-like format?

Hope this makes sense.

I know there are good tools such as Protege, VisualDataWeb for great use in achieving the same goals.  But I'm really wondering what else is available out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Topbraid Composer](http://www.topquadrant.com/products/TB_Composer.html) is the most complete tool I'm aware of in this space.

Be aware that SELECT results are tabular, not graph like, although you can think of the original query as a 'gappy graph' and bind results to it. ([RDFAuthor](http://danbri.org/words/2005/09/22/136) [used this technique](http://rdfweb.org/people/damian/RDFAuthor/Tutorial/Tutorial2/))

Comment: Thanks for that!  That link certainly looks very helpful indeed! Maybe it is something close to what we're thinking of having as a great tool!